# App Doesnt show up in Android Virtual Device

Tags: android

Im new to android studio and I created a new project with empty layout and tries to run it on a virtual Device , however the phone does show up and runs perfectly but my application doesnt show up anywhere in the menu on the virtual device , can i get some help here ?

I did read the manual but im just so confused about how a newly created project/app doesnt show up in the virtual device, the following error also exists when i tries to run it again when the virtual device is running in the background .

com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device unauthorized.
This adb server's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set
Try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong.
Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device.
Error while Installing APK

Comment: Make sure you have  `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />` as intent-filter in your launcher activity also check if icons are in the correct drawable folders.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , I have double checked and the code is there, my biggest guess would be a older version of android studio I got back in 2018 was not updated properly and impacting the current version which causes the error.

Comment: Can you please share your Manifest here ?. The second error is related to instant run check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53916433/3111083

Comment: I havent modified any code after creating the empty layout and project so everything is basically default

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions:

- Try to **delete** the AVD and create a new one, then see if the problem occurs again.
- Try to delete **adbkey** file in C:\Users\yourname.android

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried both method but the same error still exists, the virtual machine works completely fine by itself but it only shows default applications  on it .

Comment: When you try to run it for the first time you see an error on the build log? Or simply the app doesn't appear?

Comment: When I run it for the first time , The phone appears but the App doesnt appear in it . If i try to run it again , there's 2 deployment target devices I can choose from , connected device: emulator-5554[OFFLINE] and Available Virtual Devices( Nexus 5X API 28) , and if pick the first option I got the error mentioned in the description.

Comment: Do you see down the page in android studio if the build is completed and apk is installed correctly? Without errors?

Comment: When I click the play button and tries to run the app , the only thing that shows up in the Log is "Lauching app" without any errors, but I could not locate the the application in the virtual machine.

Comment: Have you tried on a physical device or on a different AVD or also a different version of Android?

Comment: Tried a different AVD/version and Re-installing but nothing helps. Basically when I first run the application no error generates, the phone pops out but the application wasnt on it . When I try to run the app again with the phone already open , I got the following error " Instant Run is not supported on devices with API levels 20 or lower." and om.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: device unauthorized. This adb server's $ADB_VENDOR_KEYS is not set Try 'adb kill-server' if that seems wrong. Otherwise check for a confirmation dialog on your device. Error while Installing APK

Comment: Did you try `adb kill-server` and then `adb start-server`? After that what is the output of `adb status` when your emulator is running?

Answer (score 0):

A clean manual Uninstallation of android studio solved the issue , thanks everyone for the help.